# Avoid 'undefined' in JS

Tags: reactjs

I built an app using routes in React Js. I have some pages in my app which are in my routes. Also, I have created an array:

```
const routes = [{
    path: "/home",
    title: "home"
},
  {
    path: "/about",
    title: "about"
    }
];
```

This array contains my breadcrumbs. The logic is next: if the URL matches the route from `routes`, I display the `title` from `routes`. But, I don't want use the `about` page. When I will click on about page I want to display also `title` from home page. The problem is when I click on about page I get the next error:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

How can I hide this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as follows:

```
const myvar = object ? object.name : undefined;
```

Comment: After you edited your question, my answer lost its context. You should revert to the original question and create a new post for this new issue.